# Calling a function within a dynamically created form - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, dynamically-generated, populate

As part of my project, I'm dynamically creating a form, like so:

```
        Dim thisticket As New ViewTicket
        thisticket.Text = "Ticket " & ticketnumber
        thisticket.ticketid = ticketnumber
        thisticket.ShowDialog()
```

This form contains a function 'PopulateHistory()', which when called, goes off and grabs all the relevant history for this ticket from the db.

One of the options on that form allows you to update the ticket history by either generating an email, adding a document etc; The ticket update options open in another form with showdialog() and topmost = true.

Once the user has completed whatever update they are doing, the Update form is closed and I want to then call the 'PopulateHistory()' function again, to cause the history datagridview to refresh and show the most recent history.

Before created 'thisticket as New ViewTicket', I could have just said ViewTicket.PopulateHistory() and it would have done it, but not that I have created the form dynamically, I cant call the function in that way.

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you now have an instance you have to call methods of the instance itself.

Instead of `ViewTicket.PopulateHistory()` do `thisticket.PopulateHistory()`

Comment: I thought it should be that simple, but when i try this, I get an error...
'thisticket' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Make sure that the variable `thisticket` (that is holding the `ViewTicket` instance) exists and is visible from the calling context. You have to call it after the instantiation `Dim thisticket As New ViewTicket`

Comment: The form I'm trying to call the populatehistory() function from is like a sub-form of 'thisticket' called 'ticketupdate'.
User opened 'thisticket', user adds an update, so 'ticketupdate' is shown. in the close event of 'ticketupdate' is where I am trying to say thisticket.populatehistory(), so it would definitely be after 'Dim thisticket As New ViewTicket' as that happens as soon as the user opens the ticket

Comment: The variable doesn't exist in the ticketupdate context. You have to pass it to the ticketupdate class to use it.

Comment: how do I pass it to the class? sorry if thats a dumb question

Comment: We're going off topic

Comment: I disagree - If I have to pass it to the ticketupdate class to resolve my issue, then thats surely on topic?

Answer (score 0):

Since `thisticket` is the new `ViewTicket` now,

then call it like this:

```
thisticket.PopulateHistory()
```

`thisticket` also inherited the functions inside `ViewTicket` thus you can call the function like that.